# Anonymous and authenticated users for same firewall in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have two firewalls for auth and api. But i want to combine them and be able to check if there is some user in controller.

```
firewalls:
    user:
        pattern:  ^/api/auth
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path:               /api/auth/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/auth,     roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

What I want to do is to combine firewalls to one and allow any user everythere, but still be available to identify user if JWT passwed.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please tell which version of symfony you are using in order to ease other users find a solution to your issue

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,to achieve this you will need only the firewall matching **^/api** pattern and continue using guard authenticator. Then, inside your authenticator, check for the exact route requested and chose whether to continue with normal guard authenticator flow or use a custom logic to implement json login. But it is a little bit dirty even if guard permits you to implement your own logic. Keeping separated firewalls sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to keep separate firewalls, as mentioned already, but in case you absolutely need to keep your application open to everybody and check if the user is authenticated in your controller, you can refer to symfony's [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) and use something like:

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
```

Comment: I read this docs a few times. Still cant combine json_login, jwt guard, and anon users in one firewall.